# How can I display a loading state until a song loaded with www.GetAudioClip() is ready to play?

Tags: unity, c#, sound, loading

I use `www.GetAudioClip()` to get a song and play it when my Android mobile game starts.

My issue is that it takes a 3-second delay to play the song.

My idea is to add some loading screen before starting the game, and the game starts after `www.GetAudioClip()` finishes getting the song and I begin to play it. But I don't know how to control the loading screen so it disappears after the right delay.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds great, why don't you add a loading screen? What exactly do you need help for?

Comment: @TomTsagk good sir  i don't no how to  add  loading  screen that stop after www.GetAudioClip()  complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a coroutine you start by calling `StartCoroutine(LoadSongWithLoadingScreen(songURL));`

```
IEnumerator LoadSongWithLoadingScreen(string url) {

    // Show your loading screen.
    loadingVisuals.SetActive(true);

    // Start the download.
    var request = new WWW(url);

    // Wait for the download to finish,
    // letting the game continue running
    // and animating in the meantime.
    yield return request;

    // TODO: check for & handle network errors.

    // Hide loading screen.
    loadingVisuals.SetActive(false);

    // Use your song.
    song = www.GetAudioClip();
    PlaySong(song);
}
```